# PHP как удалить объект из его метода?

Tags: php, классы, объекты, unset

Есть класс который описывает строку таблицы `BaseModel` у него много наследников для каждой таблицы в БД (например: `OrderModel`).

У базовой модели есть метод `delete`, который выглядит так:

```
     /**
     * This function should be overriden if needed
     * @return boolean(true|false)
     */
    public function beforeDelete() { return true; }

    /**
     * This function should be overriden if needed
     * @return boolean(true|false)
     */
    public function afterDelete() { return true; }

    /**
     * Remove record from DB
     * @throws UnexpectedValueException when trying to remove record with unknown id or id < 0
     * @throws RuntimeException if afterDelete() didn't work properly
     * @return boolean(true|false)
     *
     * @uses Database::exec()
     * @uses $this->beforeDelete()
     * @uses $this->afterDelete()
     */
    public function delete()
    {
        if (empty($this->id) || $this->id < 0) {
            throw new UnexpectedValueException('Can`t delete record with unset ID in '.__CLASS__.
                ', see file '.__FILE__.' at line '.__LINE__);
        }
        if ($this->beforeDelete()) {
            $sql = 'DELETE FROM `'.static::$tableName.'`
                WHERE `'.static::$fields['id'].'`=:'.static::$fields['id'];

            $pdoArgs = array();
            $pdoArgs[] = array('param' => ':'.static::$fields['id'], 'arg' => $this->id,
                'type' => static::$pdoTypes[static::$fieldTypes['id']]);

            if (Database::getInstance()->exec($sql, $pdoArgs)) {
                if ($this->afterDelete()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    throw new RuntimeException('Model has been deleted but afterDelete() don`t work correct, class '.__CLASS__.
                        ', see file '.__FILE__.' at line '.__LINE__);
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Интересует как удалить объект класса в методе `afterDelete()`, так как модель остается доступна и для нее можно вызвать метод `save()` и т.д.

Пример: допустим у нас есть список заказов, я его обхожу `foreach-ем` и удаляю не подтвержденные модели (вызовом метода `->delete()`), а потом запускаю еще один `foreach` что бы разослать заказы `->send()`. Но в списке все по прежнему останутся объекты которые удалены. Как сделать для них правильный unset.

Comment: Не до конца понял вопрос, но, если все же понял правильно, то: 1) удалить объект из самого себя нельзя, 2) в качестве костыля я бы сделал в классе метод isValid(), возвращающий false если объект подлежит удалению и во втором foreache'е, с send'ом unset'ил бы невалидные объекты

Comment: Вы удаляете из базы, сделайте `unset` ненужных моделей в коллекции

Comment: @Naumov Вы меня правильно поняли. Возможно ли это сделать внутри модели, что бы это не делать каждый раз в ручную?

Comment: Так вам нужно удалить из коллекции, некого массива, а модель  ниже этого обсервера, чисто теоретически можно попытаться, конечно передать по ссылке эту коллекцию в модель и там уже удолять. Но это уже как то звучит даже страшно.

Comment: @Naumov Как по мне странно что я не могу сделать внутри своего метода `unset($this);` и у меня в коллекции появятся `null`.

Comment: Помойму ничего странного, у вас как коллекция реализованна как interator или как простой массив объектов, и я так понимаю он находиться в регистре. По идеи можно как рас в коллекции реализовать метод, точнее он там есть что наподобие `unsetItem`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объект хранится в оперативной памяти, а то, что вы имеете — ссылки на эту память. Объект жив до тех пор, пока на него существует хотя бы одна ссылка.
Так что можете вызвать `unset($this)` сколько угодно, т.к. это не приведёт ни к какому результату.

Удалить же псевдо-переменную `$this` невозможно.

Вывод — удалять нужно там где хранятся ссылки на объект.

---

P.S.

[PDO::exec()](http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.exec.php) возвращает количество строк, поэтому при успешном запросе не удалившем ни одной строки у вас вылетит `RuntimeException`

Comment: Спасибо за P.S. так и задумано. Так как если действительно удалена строка вернет true, если есть проблемы будет false, Exeption же вылетет только если в моделе есть косяк который нужно фиксить.